# How to get a translated string from a language other than the current one?

Tags: translation, multi-language, localization, language, l10n

I was wandering... All the translation functions (`__(), _e(), _x()` and so on) use the current/active language. Is there a way to get a translation from another language than the current one? For example, I'm on a French page and I want and english translation: how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to J.D., I finally ended up with this code:

```
function __2($string, $textdomain, $locale){
  global $l10n;
  if(isset($l10n[$textdomain])) $backup = $l10n[$textdomain];
  load_textdomain($textdomain, get_template_directory() . '/languages/'. $locale . '.mo');
  $translation = __($string,$textdomain);
  if(isset($bkup)) $l10n[$textdomain] = $backup;
  return $translation;
}


function _e2($string, $textdomain, $locale){
  echo __2($string, $textdomain, $locale);
}
```

Now, I know it shouldn't be, as per this famous article:

http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/

But, I don't know, it works... And bonus: say you want to use it in admin, because the admin language is x, but you want to get/save data in lang y, and you're using polylang. So i.e. your admin is english, but you're on the spanish translation of a post, and you need to get spanish data from your theme locales:

```
global $polylang;
$p_locale = $polylang->curlang->locale; // will be es_ES
_e2('your string', 'yourtextdomain', $p_locale)
```

Answer (score 3):

To find the answer to this question, you just need to look at how WordPress retrieves the translations. Ultimately it is the [`load_textdomain()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_textdomain/#source) function that does this. When we take a look at its source we find that it creates a `MO` object and loads the translations from a `.mo` file into it. Then it stores that object in a global variable called `$l10n`, which is an array keyed by textdomain.

To load a different locale for a particular domain, we just need to call `load_textdomain()` with the path to the `.mo` file for that locale:

```
$textdomain = 'your-textdomain';

// First, back up the default locale, so that we don't have to reload it.
global $l10n;

$backup = $l10n[ $textdomain ];

// Now load the .mo file for the locale that we want.
$locale  = 'en_US';
$mo_file = $textdomain . '-' . $locale . '.mo';

load_textdomain( $textdomain, $mo_file );

// Translate to our heart's content!
_e( 'Hello World!', $textdomain );

// When we are done, restore the translations for the default locale.
$l10n[ $textdomain ] = $backup;
```

To find out what logic WordPress uses to determine where to look for the `.mo` file for a plugin (like how to get the current locale), take a look at the source of [`load_plugin_textdomain()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_plugin_textdomain/#source).

Comment: But where does the first $textdomain come from?

Comment: Indeed, where does it come from? For example, one of my actions/filters wont get the correct locale, when others do. How to figure this one out? It's "pending_to_publish" hook for example ... if I want to send emails there, they are always in a defined language whereas in "transition_post_status" hook it gets the correct language. Any thoughts?

Comment: @trainoasis I've updated the example to show example values, but you can see how to get the current locale from the source of `load_plugin_textdomain()`.

Comment: I updated the code below, because I found out that sometimes `$l10n[$textdomain]` is not setted, even after loading the text domain in a `after_setup_theme` action.

Answer (score 0):

It all really depends on your use case. I'm more adept of switching WordPress altogether as even WP localised functions such as `wp_date` will work as expected.

For instance, let's say you need translated content in a cron job depending on the user locale, you can programmatically switch WP locale.

```
// Get user locale if needed
$user_locale = get_user_locale($user_id);

// Now change WP locale if needed
if ($user_locale !== get_locale()) switch_to_locale($user_locale);
```

After that, all core functions will be localised and calls to any of the translation functions (`__()`, `_e()`, `_x()`) will be in the required locale.

The [`switch_to_locale`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_locale/) function was added in WP 4.7. Nothing prevents you from switching in back afterwards.

Comment: The `$user_locale !== get_locale()` check is superfluous. `switch_to_locale()` simply does nothing if the locale isn't different.