# Force language in translate function

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multi-language, localization, language

In WordPress, I can easily get the translated string with current language with

```
$s = __('string', 'domain');
```

However, if I am currently in `en`, if I want to get the Japanese version of string, is it possible?

Something like below..

```
$s = __('string', 'domain', 'ja');
```

How to do with the same effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231685/how-to-get-a-traslated-string-from-a-language-other-than-the-current-one?rq=1

Comment: If you want to change the language for a whole plugin have a look at the plugin_locale filter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugin_locale/