# Changing wp admin user's language does not update all of the plugin localizations in backend

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, localization

I have a custom MU plugin `mup` for which I've coded some custom admin pages. For these and all of their related strings; I've successfully created the according `.mo` files and placed them all both in:

`wp-content/languages/plugins/`
`wp-content/mu-plugins/mup/languages/`

My text domain is loaded in the main plugin file of `mup` via (this actually fails if called on a page using the default language, no idea why, but this is [another issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/393290/how-to-properly-load-text-domain-of-custom-mu-plugin)):

```
add_action(
        'init',
        function() {
          $check = load_muplugin_textdomain( 'mup', 'mup/languages' );
          if (! $check) {echo "ohoh";}
        }
      );
```

Let's say you load an admin page `X`, for which you've localized all the contents via `__()` functions. You then go to the user account edits in the wp admin, and change the language of your user, let's say from english to german.
You then go back to your admin page `X`, and at first sight it all appears to be in german, and not in english anymore, so the language switch worked ok. BUT, as soon as you make a client - server request on that page, e.g. via AJAX, which is part of your `mup` plugin: Surprize, every localized string coming from the server via `__()` again appears in english, and not in german! Also, when I echo out the current locale via `global $locale; echo $locale;` I weirdly get `EN_GB`, although the entire page content is shown in german. WTH is going on...?

Comment: This is the same question you asked about in 2 other questions but phrased in the context of AJAX. If your textdomain fails to load then it is unreasonable to expect other things that require it to be loaded to work. You should focus on one aspect of the problem at a time

Comment: No it is not the same, because it gets triggered as soon as I switch the admin user's language. Before that it all works perfectly well! I'm sorry Tom but you keep commenting that my answer is the same as another one; yet it's always about something really different, as stated in my question. I'm also digging and researching all this time; just thinking that it may be due to some hooking I forgot of my custom plugin to the admin user language switch; for plugin localizations to work properly, if that's even necessary. Hence the reason of this question here.

Comment: And thanks for your continuous reply; so you think this has nothing to do with admin user language switches? If you're sure about that we can close this question; no problem.

Comment: I'm confused, you've just described your other question in terms that exactly match this question. Please be more specific and clear. What do you mean by admin user language switches? All AJAX requests or just your plugins AJAX requests? Simplify things, and describe things as they are, not as you theorise them to be

Comment: Yes because the problem A is maybe linked with problem B, but I don't know if yes or not, which is why I'm asking. All I know is that I can trigger problems / errors in relation to loading the text domain and switching the admin language; but I don't know which error causes which problems (if only...). Could we may talk about this in the stack chat real quick?

Comment: This is a great way to confuse people, I'm closing this as a duplicate as it's just another theory to try and solve the same problem. You should ask about your problem, not proposed solutions or theories, by separating those out into new questions you confuse users, conceal useful information to users who only found your other questions, and spam the site with endless variations of the same question but with different spins/theories

Comment: I understand your frustration; yet my questions are all about a different action X which caused a different error Y, so I thought it to be even more confusing to list all of these 3 things in the same question.... Anyway, thx a lot for ur help